# Android - My own Tile - ImageButton + TextField

Tags: android

My question is about building my own ImageButton. 
I want to have all of things that have ImageButton, but i want to add some TextField on it.
So i want to create component which have:

1. Square size
2. Image on top with: 100% width, 80% height
3. TextField on bottom: 100% width, 20% height
4. All square "tile" must be clickable and working as normaly button

Something like this:

[image]

How to do that?
It will be very very nice when You can provide some code for this, but in minimum option I will be very grateful for some "todo list" in point what should i do step by step.

Comment: Does it have to be an `ImageButton` ? Can't you just design it in XML and add a `OnClickListener` to a `Layout` ?

Comment: @JonZarate yea, this is maybe a good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following layout: for 80% and 20% height use `android:layout_weight` attribute

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".80"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:text="left" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Sample Text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks it looks good. And what You suggest to do in .java? Create java file with controller for this linearLayout and then implement listener on this or what?

Comment: you can inflate the layout in your grid adapter getView() method and add click listener to whole `LinearLayout `

Answer (score 1):

Basically we are making a relative layout (parent) which will be our 'image button'. Xml code is below, for Java you just need to implement the setonclicklistener on this id.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/page_image"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/no_photo" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/page_name"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/page_image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/page_image"
        android:layout_below="@id/page_image
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the clickListener must be implemented on some "mainActivity.java" class or it will be better to create the other class "myComponent.java" as a controller to one tile with listener, and then import this in mainActivity? What will be the good practic?

Comment: Creating a class and extending Relative Layout just to override a single OnClickListener method would increase the overhead.
You can just create an object this Relative Layout and implement the onClickListener on it.